# aws boto3 library, the function describe_key_pairs doesn't return public key field as in documentation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

```
response = self.ec2.describe_key_pairs(
        KeyNames=[
             name,
        ],
        IncludePublicKey=True,
).get("KeyPairs")
```

documentation for boto2  1.34.61

The response object should have a
'PublicKey': 'string'

I was expecting the public key in the response.

Do I have to get the public key from the private key?

Comment: What's the output of `print(boto3.__version__)`?

Comment: version of boto3 is  1.34.62

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code:

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = ec2_client.describe_key_pairs(IncludePublicKey=True)

for key in response['KeyPairs']:
    print(key['PublicKey'])
```

It displayed the public keys associated with each keypair.

This last line also works:

```
    print(key.get('PublicKey'))
```